# Cordova: W/AccessibilityInjector﹕ Error parsing JS JSON object?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, talkback

Am developing Cordova (Phonegap) application. while talk-back is enabled in device (accessibility), on reading my web-view UI elements am getting these error frequently. But the same UI is working fine in IOS.

```
09-24 02:39:34.225    7096-7173/com.mdlive.mobile W/AccessibilityInjector﹕ Error parsing JS JSON object
org.json.JSONException: No value for text
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.AccessibilityInjector$TextToSpeechWrapper.braille(AccessibilityInjector.java:451)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```